# 2 Discrete Random Variables Problems...

Tags: statistics

If I have 2 discrete variables, $X$ & $Y$ where X takes values in $\{ 1,2 \}$ and Y takes values in $\{0,1,2 \}$. The joint PMF is given by the table:

[image]

I need to be able to determine the marginal distributions for $X = 1$ and $X = 2$ and $Y = 0,Y = 1 \ \& \ Y = 2$. I also need to find the expected value of $X, Y \ \& \ XY$. I have no idea how to do any of this. Any hints are appreciated.

EDIT: I know how to calculate the covariance now.

Comment: The table of the joint pmf is missing.

Comment: I have put the HTML code in there. I thought someone had edited my post but it is there, it just isn't showing up. The image is at http://i63.tinypic.com/2cag6o.png. Thank you for catching the error on the answer to my previous question (and of course, for your own comments).

Comment: Some hints: For the marginal distributions you just have to sum up the values. For instance P(X=1)=$0.101+0.058+0.181=0.34$. And $P(X=2)=1-0.34=0.66$. The expected value of X is $E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^2 P(X=x)\cdot x=0.34\cdot 1 +0.66\cdot  2$

Comment: **Quote**:"*I need to be able to determine the marginal distributions for X=1 and X=2 and Y=0,Y=1 & Y=2.*" You only can determine margnial distributions for $X$ or $Y$. If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: So the expected value of X is 1.66 and that of Y is 1.005 - correct? How would I find $E(XY)$? Thank you for that, I appreciate it when you correct my misconceptions and give me some conceptual understanding rather than just helping with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected value of $XY$ is

$E(XY)= \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=0}^2 \ \ x_i\cdot y_i\cdot P(X=x_i,Y=y_j)$

$=\underbrace{1\cdot 0\cdot 0.101+ 1\cdot 1+0.058+1\cdot 2 \cdot 0.181}_{i=1,j=0,1,2} \ \ + \ \underbrace{2\cdot 0\cdot 0.221+ 2\cdot 1+0.293+2\cdot 2 \cdot 0.146}_{i=2,j=0,1,2}$

The first expression with the underbrace is the sum from $j=0$ to $j=2$ and $i$ is constant $i=1$. It is the sum of the first row. For every summand the values of X and Y are multiplied. Additionally this result has to be multiplied by the corresponding value of $P(X=x_1,Y=y_j)$.

**Remark**

You mentioned something about calculating the value of the covariance. If you know the value of $E(XY)$, then it is easy to calculate the covariance, because

$Cov(X,Y)=E(X\cdot Y)-E(X)\cdot E(Y)$

Comment: Yes, I found that about covariance in my notes and so removed it from the question. E(XY) = 1.42 then. If I understand then $E(XX) = \sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^2 {\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^2 {x_i^2 \cdot P(X = {x_i},X = {x_i})} } $. If so, I don't see how that could be calculated.

Comment: You only need one sigma sign: $E(XX)=E(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i^2\cdot P(X=x_i)$. Another useful relation in this context $Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$ (variance decomposition).